# Either monad to IO monad - simple and idiomatic way?

Tags: haskell, monads

This code compiles:

```
read :: IO Config
read = do
  c1 <- BS.readFile "my_config.yaml"
  case Y.decodeEither' c1 of
    Right x -> pure x
    Left e -> error "error 123"
```

where this doesn't:

```
read :: IO Config
read = do
  liftIO $ case (BS.readFile "my_config.yaml") >>= Y.decodeEither' of
    Right x -> pure x
    Left e -> error "error 123"
```

===>

```
  Expected type: IO Config
    Actual type: Either a1 Config
```

How can I transform Either monad to IO one? I'd like a simple and idiomatic way, with no additional libraries.

Comment: I think you should prefer `fail` (a well-defined `IO` action which throws an exception) to `error` (an undefined `IO` action). Recovery, in case that ever becomes a thing you want to do, is more straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `BS.readFile "my_config.yaml" >>= Y.decodeEither'` does not make much sense, since [**`decodeEither' :: FromJSON a => ByteString -> Either ParseException a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yaml-0.11.3.0/docs/Data-Yaml.html#v:decodeEither-39-) itself does not return an `IO a`, and `BS.readFile` is not an `Either ParseException b`, so it has neither an `IO` monadic context, or an `Either a` monadic context.

What you can do is perform a functor mapping on the result, so `Y.decodeEither' <$> BS.readFile "my_config.yaml"`, but then this has as type `FromJSON a => IO (Either ParseException a)`, so you can not use pattern matching with `Left` and `Right` on that.

You can however implement this as:

```
read :: IO Config
read = do
    result <- Y.decodeEither <$> BS.readFile "my_config.yaml"
    case result of
        Right x -> pure x
        Left e -> error e
```

or you can, like [@JosephSible says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61289988/either-monad-to-io-monad-simple-and-idiomatic-way/61290270?noredirect=1#comment108432614_61290270) perform the mapping in the `case` part:

```
read :: IO Config
read = do
    result <- BS.readFile "my_config.yaml"
    case Y.decodeEither result of
        Right x -> pure x
        Left e -> error e
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `do` or `liftIO` here.

```
read :: IO Config
read = Y.decodeEither' <$> BS.readFile "my_config.yaml" >>= \c -> case c of
                                                                  Right x -> pure x
                                                                  Left  e -> error "error 123"
```

should do it.

However it could be nicer to use the [`ExceptT` transformer](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html) then all you need to do would be

```
read :: ExceptT ParseException IO Config
read =  ExceptT $ Y.decodeEither <$> BS.readFile "my_config.yaml"
```

Now you can do like;

```
configure :: ExceptT ParseException IO ()
configure =  read >>= pure . processConfig
```

or as reminded by @Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica like

```
configure :: ExceptT ParseException IO ()
configure = processConfig <$> read
```

and if `decodeEither` returns a `Left` value it gets logged and `processConfig :: Config -> ()` gets skipped.

Comment: Why `read >>= pure . processConfig` and not `processConfig <$> read`?

Comment: Why `Y.decodeEither' <$> BS.readFile "my_config.yaml" >>= \c -> case c of` and not `BS.readFile "my_config.yaml" >>= \c -> case Y.decodeEither' c of`?

Comment: @Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica Yes... that would be essentially better and it was indeed my initial attempt but then i edited it out with the intensions of preparing OP for what's coming next.

Comment: @Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica i overlooked your first comment... Yes it could be a nice way to remind `ExceptT` is a functure.

Answer (score 1):

```
read :: IO Config
read = do
  liftIO $ case (BS.readFile "my_config.yaml") >>= Y.decodeEither' of
    Right x -> pure x
    Left e -> error "error 123"
```

In the above incorrect attempt it almost looks like you want -XLambdaCase:

```
    fmap Y.decodeEither' (BS.readFile "my_config.yaml) >>= \case
        Right x -> pure x
        Left e -> error "error 123"
```

But I find `either` more readable:

```
    either (error "error 123") pure . Y.decodeEither' =<< BS.readFile "my_config.yaml"
```